# Create an instance of object internally

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have tried to create an instance of object internally like the following:

```
var oo = function(){
    return new func();
}

var func = function(){
    this.name;
    this.age;  
};

func.prototype = {
    setData: function(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    getData: function (){
        return this.name + " " + this.age;
    }
}
```

When usage, I got an error `oo.setData is not a function`.

```
oo.setData("jack", 15);
console.log(oo.getData());
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Try `oo().setData("jack", 15)`

Comment: because oo is not an instance of func, its just a function that will return an instance of func, are you trying to do inheritance?

Comment: @wZVanG: The error message disappeared, but the `getData` function return `undefined` data.

Comment: because every time you call oo() you get a new instance of func

Comment: @PatrickEvans: how to solve this problem to create the instance once?

Comment: it depends on what your end goal is. Are you trying to do inheritance? meaning oo would get the properties/methods of "func", or are you just trying to make it so you do not have to call `new func`? Why do you want to _"create it internally"_?

Comment: @PatrickEvans: to access to properties/methods of "func".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because oo is not a "func", oo **returns** a new func. You could set the data using

```
oo().setData('jack',15);
```

But then you have no way of accessing it.

You could also use

```
var newfunc = oo();
newfunc.setData('jack',15);
newfunc.getData();
```

Comment: Actually oo _is_ a function.

Comment: it is a function, but not a "func" -- which is what you created a prototype for.

Answer (score 1):

`oo` is a function to create a object.

```
var oo = function(){ //the oo variable is used to create func() objects
    return new func();
}

var func = function(){ //function
    this.name;
    this.age;  
};

func.prototype = { //define properties to func
    setData: function(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    getData: function (){
        return this.name + " " + this.age;
    }
}

//create instance
var myObject = oo();
//or
var myObject = new func();

//Use
myObject.setData("jack", 12);

//Get a property
console.log(myObject.getData())
```